# Howto set up classpath for System Groovy Script in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy

[Documentation for the Groovy Plugin of Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin) states that

> The system groovy script, OTOH, runs inside the Jenkins master's JVM.
>   Thus it will have access to all the internal objects of Jenkins, so
>   you can use this to alter the state of Jenkins. It is similar to the
>   Jenkins Script Console functionality.

Yet I find that I have a groovy script that I can successfully run in Jenkins Script Console but which does NOT run if entered as a "System Groovy Script" on a build configuration.  There are compiler errors.  Clearly, the Jenkins Script Console is running with a different classpath than the script in my build.  But I can't find information on what the default classpath is when running a script for a build or what the classpath is when running from the Script Console, so I might duplicate that for my script.

Also, the plugin offers a classpath entry field for running the script as a file but that option does not exist for entering the script as text.

I can't get my script to work either way.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is that the Script Console auto-imports the whole Jenkins library.  That is not the case with the System Groovy Script.  So what worked for me was to run the script, and for every compiler error about an unknown class, add an import statement for that class.  I learned what packages they were from by looking at Javadocs.

Automating this would be a nice improvement to the plugin.

Answer (score -1):

May be use the grab dependency management to resolve the library to add

Comment: Can you be a little more specific in your answer?  While this answer may be valid, it doesn't provide steps for how to do what you are suggesting.

Comment: 'grab' is not supported out of the box in systemGroovyCommands